# How to obtain column comments from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, comments

As you guys propably know, there's the possibility to add a comment to a column in MySQL.
Now I was wondering how I could obtain this comment via PHP/MySQL.
I was searching the web but I didn't find any solution yet.
Do you guys have any idea/solution for this problem?

Greetings!

Comment: @Chris, that link is for postgresql, and it does not mention `information_schema` how is that useful?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_COMMENT
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db-name' AND
    TABLE_NAME = 'table-name' AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'column-name'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html

Comment: As a bonus, you can use `DATABASE()` to get the current default database name.

Comment: Very cool, didn't realize you could select the comment column as a pseudo field

Comment: you can use same data base with `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` in @AlienWebguy response

Comment: How can I get a array containing all COLUMN_CONTENT 's ?

Answer (score 8):

Just use this SQL:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM myTable
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

> The FULL keyword causes the output to include the column collation and comments, as well as the privileges you have for each column.

Answer (score 2):

Data regarding MySQL's tables in stored in the `information_schema` views.
You should be able to get it from there. This requires root privileges.

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_comment 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`columns` c
WHERE c.table_schema = 'mydatabase' 
  AND c.table_name = 'mytable'
  AND c.column_name = 'myfield'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have correct privileges you could make this query:

```
$query = "SHOW FULL COLUMNS from node;";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

And then fetch the results (there is a column named `Comment` that holds the comments)

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch those metadata from the `information_schema` database.

Ex:

`SELECT column_name, column_comment FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'user'`

Where user is your table name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL command `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` as described [in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-columns.html). Its output contains the comments.