# How to obtain SQL column comments

Tags: apache-spark

There are important metadata registered in the tables by

```
create table t1 (
  column1 type COMMENT '... the comments1...',
  column2 type COMMENT '... the comments2...'
  ...
);
```

in our database hundreds of tables, and hundreds of column's `COMMENT` for each table.

We need Spark or HQL statement to obtain SQL column comments.

How to do **some serious information retrieval about it?** I need it as a [first class table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen),... Or, if it is impossible, a **JSON** or [standard MIME CSV file](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc4180) with all metadata.

---

NOTES:

- We use both, direct Hive SQL and Spark, so any answer (HQL or Scala/Spark script) is valid.
- Not need [to **scrape**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping) *SHOW/DESCRIBE TABLES* command, need serious solution.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6752169/287948) is similar, but restricted to MySQL... The only clue is to do some direct acess to the Metastore (in our config seems Derby SQL schema - no standard).
- [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57401967/287948) also about "serious information retrieval" of metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the comments through the DataFrame schema using `StructField.getComment()`

For example if you want to manipulate the comments as a dataframe

```
// create a demo table
spark.sql("create table t1 (id long comment 'this is an example comment')")

// load table as dataframe
val t1 = spark.table("t1")

// load column comments as dataframe
val commentsDf1 = t1.schema.map(f => (f.name,f.getComment)).toDF("name","comment")

// check that everything is loaded correctly
commentsDf1.show(false)
+----+--------------------------+
|name|comment                   |
+----+--------------------------+
|id  |this is an example comment|
+----+--------------------------+
```

If you want to use SQL to access these comments, you can use `DESCRIBE <tablename>` to achieve the same result:

```
val commentsDf2 = spark.sql("describe t1")

commentsDf2.show(false)
+--------+---------+--------------------------+
|col_name|data_type|comment                   |
+--------+---------+--------------------------+
|id      |bigint   |this is an example comment|
+--------+---------+--------------------------+
```

---

Both, `commentsDf1` and  `commentsDf2`, are [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen): `commentsDf2` is tabular and  `commentsDf1` a little bit more richer and  complex.

Comment: Thanks! Seems an undocumented Spark feature, [getComment](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructField.html#getComment--)... Do you suggest  a link or tutorial about advanced uses of the *.schema* and schema utils?

Comment: I don't know if any exists actually.

Comment: It seems that there is no "getComment" option for Python, is that correct?

Comment: Correct but you can access (and modify) the comment using the metadata property of StructField: `StructField.metatadata.get('comment')` in Pyspark is equivalent to Scala `StructField.getComment()`

Answer (score 2):

In case you use PySpark, you can do the following:

```
for col_schema in df.schema:
    print(col_schema.metadata['comment'])
```